# How to add a new attribute to Associate Table column in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

In my rails application, I had to add a new column named `is_leader` for an association table.

The relationship for the association table is as follows:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :analysis_responses, :join_table => "analysis_responses_participants"
```

Following is the code where the participant details have been saved to the db:

```
organization.people.create(participant)
```

the `participant` has got the following values

```
name: Test User
position: 
birthdate: 
id: 
lead: "1"
```

If the lead value is 1, the `is_leader` column value should be `1` for the particular record.

I wanted to know how can I save the `is_leader` value in that association table in rails

Thanks

Comment: Not answering your question, but: it's better practice in Rails to have boolean attributes *not* be prefixed with `is_`. This practice in other languages comes in part from the lack of `?` support in the method names. Because Rails creates `?` methods for boolean attributes, it's better to just name your column `leader` and check it's value as truthy with `leader?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save attributes on the join table, then you will have to use a join model instead of a HABTM.

```
class Organization
  has_many :analysis_responses
  has_many :people, through: :analysis_responses
end

class AnalysisResponse
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  has_many :analysis_responses
  has_many :organizations, through: :analysis_reponses
end
```

Comment: Ok in this case, how can I save that leader attribute in the association table?

Comment: In my analysis_response class I've added the following:
`has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, :class_name => "Person", :join_table => "analysis_responses_participants"`

Comment: You cannot save information to a join table in `has_an_belongs_to_many`.  You will have to use a join model.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean. This helps a lot